# How do I check if a string exists in a list

Tags: python, string, list

The point of my code is to check a 4 words sentence and whether it is 4 words long.

```
import random
import time
import urllib

numwords = 4
#getWordList
wordlist = []
def getWordList() :

    url = "some word list url"
    flink = urllib.urlopen(url)
    #print "Reading words from %s" % url
    words = [ ]            # word list
    for eachline in flink :
        text = eachline.strip()
        text = text.replace('%','')
        words += [text.lower()]
    flink.close()
    #print "%d words read" % len(words)
    words.append('i','am','an','to')
    return wordlist


warning = "\n"
prompt = "Enter a sentence with four words: "
while warning:
    usrin = raw_input(warning + prompt)
    usrwords = usrin.strip().lower().split() # a list
    print "The sentence is:", ' '.join(usrwords)
    warning = ''
    if len(usrwords) != numwords: #check length
        warning += ("\n%d words sought; %d obtained \n") %(numwords, len(usrwords))
    invalid = []
    for word in usrwords:
        if word not in wordlist :
            if word not in invalid:
                invalid.append(word)
    if invalid:
        warning += ("\ninvalid words found: %s\n") %(','.join(invalid))
```

For some reasons it isn't checking my words properly, and it states that every word I enter is invalid. I was also wondering if I appended `"I am an to"` to the list properly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to believe there isn't already an answer to this question on Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: `wordlist` is empty, since you never call `getWordList`. therefore, every word is invalid.

Comment: I can't seem to edit my code because I figured out the problem, which was possibly too dumb. I fixed my wordlist function, so it works, I started my words list with the words i wanted to append to it. I forgot to call my function into my while loop and after I did that, my code seems to work

Comment: Why call `getWordList` inside the loop and retrieve the wordlist over and over again?

Comment: @Hyperboreus yeah, i seen that and fixed it thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your original question:

> How do I check if a string exists in a list

With the `in` operator:

```
>>> a = ['i', 'am', 'here', 42, None, ..., 0.]
>>> 'i' in a
True
>>> 'you' in a
False
>>> 'a' in a
False
```

Reading a bit your code, it seems you want to identify all the words in one list, which don't figure in the other ("invalid words").

```
invalid = {word for word in userWords if word not in validWords}
```

Example:

```
>>> validWords = ['I', 'am']
>>> userWords = ['I', 'well', 'am', 'well']
>>> {word for word in userWords if word not in validWords}
{'well'}
```

---

> I was also wondering if I appended "I am an to" to the list properly.

No need to wonder. When you get an error, you are generally not doing it properly:

```
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (4 given)
```

---

**EDIT**

I was so free as to change a bit of your code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

NUMWORDS = 4
#you get your wordlist from somewhere else
wordlist = ['i', 'am', 'a', 'dog']

while True:
    usrwords = raw_input("\nEnter a sentence with four words: ").strip().lower().split()
    print "The sentence is: {}".format(' '.join(usrwords))
    if len(usrwords) != NUMWORDS:
        print "\n{} words sought; {} obtained \n".format(NUMWORDS, len(usrwords))
        continue
    invalid = {word for word in usrwords if word not in wordlist}
    if invalid:
        print "\ninvalid words found: {}\n".format(', '.join(invalid))
        continue
    print 'Congratulations. You have entered a valid sentence: {}'.format(' '.join(usrwords))
    #do here whatever you must
```

Comment: Well, in fairness, `getWordList()` is never called in the given code, so it might be that the error was never actually seen.

Comment: @femtoRgon Right. Thank you. Dear OP, actually running your code is generally a good benchmark about whether you are doing something properly or not.

Comment: your comment on my double/triple negative check or w.e it is does work, I just didn't call my function

Comment: @BobUnger I didn't intend to say that your nested if's don't work, but maybe `{w for w in usrwords if w not in wordlist}` is a bit more concise and legible.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
words.append('i','am','an','to')
```

should be replaced by one of the following:

```
words = []
# Add the list ['i','am','an','to'] at the end of the list 'words'
words.append(['i','am','an','to'])
print words # outputs [['i', 'am', 'an', 'to']]
# If you want to add each individual words at the end of the list
words = []
words.extend(['i','am','an','to'])    
print words # outputs ['i', 'am', 'an', 'to']
```

Comment: somewhat what I did. i went words = ['i', 'am','an','to] then appended my url to that list

Answer (score 0):

> also wondering if I appended (I am an to) to the list properly.

The `wordlist` name is first assigned outside of `getWordList()` at file scope.  This is almost certainly not what you want.

Try changing it like so:

```
def getWordList() :
    url = "some word list url"
    flink = urllib.urlopen(url)

    words = []            # word list
    for eachline in flink.read().split('\n') :
        text = eachline.strip()
        text = text.replace('%','')
        words.append(text.lower())
    flink.close()
    #print "%d words read" % len(words)
    #words.extend('i','am','an','to')
    return words
```

Also, consider `urllib2` instead.

Comment: Brian, which version of python are using? Both 2.x and 3.x throw `TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (4 given)` on my box.

Comment: @Hyperboreus yeah that is the problem, so I started my word list including those strings